# Aceder a variáveis Rasor dentro de um foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

Estou tentando listar o conteúdo de uma tabela, mostrando em cada item os itens de outra tabela que mantém uma relação com a primeira (1:N). Para isso preciso de 2 select, sendo o 2º select baseado em cada linha do resultado do 1º select. O problema é que não sei como identificar, dentro da string SELECT, o valor trazido pelo RASOR relativo ao campo id.

```
@{
    string query = "SELECT id, tituloTopico FROM Topicos";

    var resultados = base_dados.Query(query);
    foreach (var linha in resultados)
    {       
        @linha.tituloTopico        
        string query1 = "SELECT tituloCatalogo FROM Catalogos WHERE Catalogos.id_Topico = @linha.id";
        var resultados1 = base_dados.Query(query1);
        foreach (var linha1 in resultados1)
        {
            @linha1.tituloCatalogo
        }
     }
 }
```

@linha.id não é reconhecido dentro da instrução Select. Estou a usar página cshtml e rasor.

Comment: Não faça isto, este tipo de processamento deve ser no *controller* (partindo do princípio que está usando MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de lógica deve ser executado na camada do Controller (considerando que você está utilizando MVC).

Segundo [este](http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-3-com-razor-revista-net-magazine-91/22872) artigo, o Razor tem como objetivo:

> O Razor surge no ASP.NET MVC 3, trazendo o novo conceito de View Engine, que nada mais é do que um template que implementa uma sintaxe diferente para a construção das páginas Web em ASP.NET, tornando a codificação das web pages muito mais simples e dinâmica. O Razor é uma opção a mais para a construção de páginas Web, simplificando ainda mais a codificação da camada de interface. Ele é especialmente útil em aplicações ASP.NET MVC3, onde se busca um código limpo e uniforme em toda a aplicação.

Consultas em banco de dados e demais lógicas devem ser implementadas no Controller.